# enforcing Datetime and ID uniqe key, when a year field is also needed

Tags: mysql, indexing

So I have an USER_ID field and a OBJECT_ID for every row, and a DateTime field.
There's a constraining unique key for both OBJECT_ID and USER_ID, To prevent multiple uses of the user with that object.

I now need to add a DateTime field as for when the user used the object.

I also need to constrain usage by year. So for example:

USER_ID:3
OBJECT_ID:2 
YEAR:2018
DATETIME:01-02-2018

Making the USER_ID, OBJECT_ID and YEAR, would solve my problem, as USER 3 would be abole to use OBJECT 2 once in every year.

My dilemma is the coupling of the data. (YEAR, and DATETIME)
Is there a way to enforce a smart key in some way so that i can deduce 2018 from the DATETIME and enforce the uniqe key still?

Comment: You're going to allow duplicate user id & object id in different years?

Comment: @Ray, yes. the idea is that the user can't use an object twice in the same year

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot create a key on part of a column or the result of function applied to a column (the year of a `datetime` in this case).  You need to create a `YEAR(4)` column and change the existing UNIQUE key to use that.

However, if you're using MySql 5.7 or later (and say innodb) you can create a virtual generated column for the YEAR and add that populated with data from the existing datetime--this way you don't need manual set or maintain it in your code.

As long as the `UNIQUE` key isn't a Primary key, you can use the virtual column in it like:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
  ADD COLUMN virtual_year YEAR(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (DATE(`actual_datetime`)) VIRTUAL
```

Then to add the key would be:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table 
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `user_id_object_id_vitual_year` (user_id, object_id, the_year)
```

Then drop your old `(user_id, object_id)` unique key that lacked the year.

Comment: So, this seems like a great way to decouple? VIRTUAL columns are calculated and not stored, this is perfect for me!